# Running spring MVC along side of JSF

Tags: jsf, spring-mvc

I want to write some new functionality in spring MVC, the problem is that the current site is written in **JSF 1.2**.

It does use spring 2.5 application context, but thats all.

I am thinking i can drop in spring MVC, write a single page in it, and then see what kind of hoops ill have to jump through to be able to have seamless sessions between spring mvc and jsf.

can someone offer some wise words to me about this venture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The session will not be a problem. It will be the same session, because it's a lower-level concept than JSF and spring-mvc.

The URL mapping of the respective servlets (the dispatcher servlet and the faces servlet) might be a problem. Your faces servlet would be mapped to `*.jsf`, and then your dispatcher servlet should be mapped to something like `/mvc/*`

The question remains whether mixing frameworks like that is a good option. I'd rather suggest using JSF everywhere in this project.

If you need some RESTful services, you can use spring-mvc, or you can use some JAX-RS provider, like CXF or RESTEasy.

Comment: well, then try it - the above two points should be sufficient.