# Spring MVC and JSF MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, jsf-2

In my web application, I was using JSF for all screens, but now for some reasons I need to use Spring MVC on some screens and JSF on other screens. I am not sure, how to integrate 2 MVC in single web application. I googled but didn;t get any good findings. Can you please comment over this or can you please send me some nice tutorials for this ?

Thanks
TM

Answer (score 1):

> **For some reason its very dangerous** why do you want to mix the two frameworks in one web application?

JSF and Spring MVC have dedicated servlets (Front Controllers) which do heavy lifting. You have to register that for Spring MVC and it should work.

Hope while planning you will not try to mix pageflow between the two like showing up data in Spring MVC and submiting to JSF or vice versa. If the page flows are independent you have to follow the simple steps of registering spring servlet.

But surely this does not sounds good, can you elaborate more on 'for some reason'.

You can see this link too, [Running spring MVC along side of JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441756/running-spring-mvc-along-side-of-jsf?rq=1)

Comment: thxx gbagga for your reply.. yes it may happen that i need to mix pageflow as well.
the point is initially i was using only JSF but as it mandates xhtml files which do not perform very good with huge amount of data on IE7-8, so i need to rule out JSF from my web application. but in application , there are 9 screens and problem is in 3 screens. So i was thinking to use Spring MVC for 3 screens and continue with JSF implementation on other screens..

Comment: welcome, if load can be reduced by using pagination may be just an idea. Mixing page flow can be challenging in some scenarios. I have never heard this thing of IE7-8 problem with xhtml files, do you have any link.